# Css counter for list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the counter increment in css on my ordered list but its not working

This is what I want to display:

```
1. Acknowledgements
   1.1 blah, blah ....
   1.2 blah, blah ....
   1.3 blah, blah ....

2. Risk Statement
   2.1 blah, blah ....
   2.2 blah, blah ....
   2.3 blah, blah ....

3. License
   3.1 blah, blah ....
   3.2 blah, blah ....
   3.3 blah, blah ....
```

But this s what is happening... http://jsfiddle.net/XQKcy/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQKcy/4/)

You were very close:

```
body {
    counter-reset: listCounter;
}
ol {
    counter-increment: listCounter;
    counter-reset: itemCounter;
    list-style:none;
}
li{
    counter-increment: itemCounter;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(listCounter) "." counter(itemCounter);
    left:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite match the desired output either.

Comment: It does get to the main problem

Comment: Ah, that looks better. I was busy scratching my head figuring out how nested counters could be used - but they can't, as there are no nested elements here. Your approach of using two separate counters is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @BoltClock - if you really want to go nuts with CSS, beyond sensible: http://jsfiddle.net/XQKcy/5/

Comment: @SW4 - in your above fiddle - you forgot the list number before the header text - updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/XQKcy/8/