# Styling ul tags. Numbered lists

Tags: html, css

I currently have this list

```
  <ul>
  <li>question1</li>
  <li>answer1</li>
  <li>question2</li>
  <li>answer2</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
  ul {
  list-style:decimal;
  }
```

Is there anyway to make every 2nd a other symbol? Tried nth-child, but sinces the list-style is on the ul tag it did not work.

Example of list, to make up for my bad explaining:

```
   1. question1
   a. answer1
   2. question2
   a. answer2
   3. question3
   and so on
```

Comment: Use HTML markup that matches the semantics of what you want to achieve (nested ordered lists).

Comment: Try `li:nth-of-type(even) {}`

Comment: Why not just use description/definition lists?

Comment: +1 for definition lists, see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2MYP/2/)

If you want to have a lot more control over the nature of the item style without over complicating the DOM, you could use also use (a bit more complex):

```
body {
    counter-reset: listCounter;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul> li:nth-child(odd):before {
    content:counter(listCounter)': ';
}
ul> li:nth-child(even):before {
    content:'A: ';
}
li {
    margin:20px 0;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    counter-increment: listCounter;
}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267039/css-counter-for-list/23267144#23267144)

Answer (score 2):

You could change your HTML markup slightly to make things more semantic. Something like this should work:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>question1
        <ul>
            <li>answer1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>question2
        <ul>
            <li>answer2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul ul {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbu7/

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should not be list. Semantically, this should be a definition list.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Coffee</dt>
        <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
    <dt>Milk</dt>
        <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Hope it helps. If you want a, b, 1, 2 you can use n-th child and ::before pseudoclass with content. Or just hardcode it in You HTML.

BTW. If you want to achieve this effect using lists, try gyss answer. But I thinks in that case, you should nest lists one inside another. Especially if there are more answers to each question. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

to apply a determined css to pair *li* items try this:

```
li {
    list-style:decimal;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    list-style:circle;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    list-style:decimal;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesnt make every other item the a) the OP states

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li:nth-child(odd){
 list-style-type: square; 
}
```

Comment: This doesnt make every other item the a) the OP states